# Magento 2 Custom REST API Update

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.3.5

If Only part of the data is to be updated then is sent the following way:

```
{
  "entity": {
    "entity_id": 1,
    "is_enable": 1,
    "name": "Hello",
    "title": "I am here"
  }
}
```

save method:

```
public function save(EntityInterface $entity)
    {
        /** @var EntityInterface|\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $entity */
        if (empty($entity->getStoreId())) {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $entity->setStoreId($storeId);
        }
        try {

            $this->resource->save($entity);
            
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException(__(
                'Could not save the Entity: %1',
                $exception->getMessage()
            ));
        }
        return $entity;
    }
```

On return $entity only the field with value from post rest is null:

```
{
    "entity_id": 1,
    "is_enable": 1,
    "name": "Hello",
    "title": "I am here",
    "store_id": null,
    "line_address1": null,
    "line_address2": null,
    "line_address3": null,
    "town": null,
    "city": null, 
}
```

Now if I use the `getById()` method and replace the `$entity` with the returned data e.g:

```
$entity = $this->getById($entity->getEntityId());
return $entity;
```

I get the full data minus fields just updated e.g:

If I change `"name": "Hi"` and  get `"name": "Hello"` It return `"name": "Hi"` on the next update call:

I have a joint table in model collection in `_initSelect`.  I noticed that my second model factory not returning the field straight away even thought it saves on the first call so after save mainTable model I use secondTable Factory to save the data related to mainTable entity E.G:

```
$this->resource->save($entity);

$secondTable = $this->secondTableFactory->create();
$secondTable->setData($entity);
$secondTable->save();
```

This work but I'm still investigating as to why it does not return the updated fields on the first call.

EDITED:
There are data for this entity id on all the field but it doesn't seem to be picking it up any one any idea?

Thanks

Comment: can you also post your getById function.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh I think the issue here is that I have a 2 table mainTable where creates the entity secondTable add entity an all the related field for that entity as for fields in main table when saved it returns straight away where fields from secondTable is saves but only returns on second call.